# Java compiler just takes into account the first digit

Tags: java, methods

If the input is 13 the compiler will just take into account the first digit that is 1.
I'll let you the java code.

```
class Max {
    static void checkFever(double choice) {
        
        // if temperature is less than 37, print "You have fever"
        if (choice > 37) {
            System.out.println("You have fever.");
        }
            else {
                System.out.println("You don't have fever.");
            }
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
           char choice;
           choice = (char) System.in.read();
            
             checkFever(choice);
             System.out.println(choice); // this will make appear the result
        
        
  }
}
```

the output is the following:

```
38
You have fever.
3
```

Comment: `char` is a single character, you probably want to read a whole `String` or more preferably a `double` or `float`

Comment: The compiler isn’t doing that, the program is.  The program is doing it because `read()` reads one byte;  for textual input, `3` is one byte and `7` is another byte.

Comment: Can you do a `System.out.println` in beginning of checkFever method?

Answer (score 2):

Use a `Scanner` that wraps the `System.in` (which is an `InputStream`) to read the whole line parsed into an appropriate primitive or object data type. In your case for the temperature `int` would be sufficient but a decimal `float` or `double` is preferred.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
double choice = scanner.nextDouble();

checkFever(choice);

System.out.println(choice);
```

Your code doesn't work because you read a *single byte* using method [`InputStream::read`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read--)

> Reads the next byte of data from the input stream. The value byte is returned as an int in the range 0 to 255.

Comment: To add to this answer, your input is being converted to `char`, so `38` is being read as `'3'`.  When converting this to double, it is `51.0`.

Answer (score 1):

`System.in.read()` reads only a single character. You can read a whole line by the `java.util.Scanner` helper class, so:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Max {
    static void checkFever(double choice) {
        
        // if temperature is less than 37, print "You have fever"
        if (choice > 37) {
            System.out.println("You have fever.");
        }
            else {
                System.out.println("You don't have fever.");
            }
        
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
           Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
           String answer = input.nextLine();
           int temp = Integer.parseInt(answer);
            
           checkFever(temp);
           System.out.println(answer); // this will make appear the result
        
        
  }
}
```

This will give a `NumberFormatException` if the user did not enter a valid integer. Feel free to improve the code. :-)

<sub>(Help: `try{...} catch(...)`)</sub>